# Can anybody recommend an HTTP debugging proxy?

Tags: linux, gnome, http-logging, http-proxy

I would like something that allows me to:

1. Inspect all HTTP(S) traffic between my computer and the Internet, including 127.0.0.1
2. Modify incoming or outgoing data
3. It would also be nice if it had a scripting subsystem for setting rules and events
4. I prefer it be a GUI application.

Please do not answer with [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/).  I am aware of WireShark and I have used it many many times and it's a great app.  I would like something that restricts it's captures to the application layer and HTTP(S) traffic only and ignores the other Internet Protocol Suite layers.  Also, it doesn't have some of the features I listed above.

Comment: A couple of rules in WireShark would be able to help you with filtering the output to what you really want to see as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a couple:

- WebScarab: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_WebScarab_Project
- Burp http://portswigger.net/proxy/

Comment: WebScarab is a fantastic tool.

Comment: You win, was hoping for some more answers.  It would be nice if somebody created a tool similar to say, "Fiddler" with Mono and GTK#.

Comment: WebScarab is now ZAP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project

Answer (score 4):

[HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech) fits this list nicely:

✔️ Can inspect any HTTP traffic, both local or to servers on the internet, with automatic one-click setup for browsers & CLI tools

✔️ You can modify both incoming or outgoing data

✔️ You can define rules for traffic, with configurable matching (method, host, specific URL, header values, etc) & handling (breakpoints, fixed responses, timeouts)

✔️ It's a GUI application:

[image: HTTP Toolkit UI screenshot]

It's also notably 100% open-source, and the standard free version includes everything you're looking for here. Full disclosure: this is my project. I've been building it for a little while now, pretty much aiming to build a version of Fiddler for us non-Windows users, for modern tools. Let me know what you think :-).

Comment: Looks very nice, but the free version seems quite limited. Can't even copy a request as curl. You'll have a hard time getting me to pay for features that I'm already used to getting for free in my browser's devtools.

Answer (score 3):

mitmproxy
An interactive TLS-capable intercepting HTTP proxy for penetration testers and software developers
https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy